# How can I print sub-items of a named argument with println!()?

Tags: rust, println

I learned about using named arguments when printing, like this:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{nombre} le gusta el {actividad}",
    nombre= {"Clemente";"Roberto"}, actividad= "futbol");
}
```

I can't figure out how to output "Roberto" instead of "Clemente". Is there any way to access sub-items? Say:

```
{nombre[1]}
```

Comment: 1) Your current code does what you ask for - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=91e713505ce77d1646f487d3699514f5. 2) Your named argument is a block, so every item except the past one is lost after its execution.

Comment: I executed the last saved run sorry about that. But is there any way to choose between X names having an arranged sub-item as much approximate as I wrote?

Comment: What's the reason to not simply use a `Vec`?

Comment: Ok, this is 100% off topic, but just out of curiosity... I am a poor Spanish speaker but I would have said "A Clemente le gusta el futbol." Hearing "Clemente" without the "a" sounds wrong. Is this a mistake?

Comment: @trentcl Both are correct, with "a" you use it when talking to somebody. Without it is a statement.

Comment: Huh! Are you a native speaker? I too was taught to use "a" because grammatically the person who likes something is an indirect object.

Answer (score 2):

`{"Clemente";"Roberto"}` is a [block expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html) not any object or value. This means that everything between the open and close curlies is evaluated as a standalone [statement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements.html). It is the same as

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = {
        "Clemente";
        "Roberto" // the return value
    }; // s is set to "Roberto"

    println!("{nombre} le gusta el {actividad}",
        nombre=s, actividad= "futbol");
}
```

so when the `println!` evaluates the format arguments, it only receives the returned `"Roberto"` so that is what is printed. Everything else in that block is lost, unless a value from an external scope was mutated.

If you were meaning to store the two names in a [collection](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/), and print one or the other using indices, you would need to define a collection and index that: `["Clemente", "Roberto"][0]`. You cannot index the named argument inside the formatting string (such as `println!({nombre[0]} ...`) because it is really just a name which is replaced with the associated value.

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{nombre} le gusta el {actividad}",
        nombre=["Clemente", "Roberto"][0], actividad="futbol");
}
```

Better yet, define the collection before the `println!` so its easier to read and maintain later! This is not required just a suggest, and generally held to be a best practice.

```rust
fn main() {
    let nombres = ["Clemente", "Roberto"]];

    println!("{nombre} le gusta el {actividad}",
        nombre=nombres[0], actividad="futbol");
}
```